# Retrieve page objects with file_get_contents

Tags: php, object

I have seen a lot of questions and explanations about retrieving JSON objects from some page using the file_get_contents, but, what if the object have its instance in the page and it's not a JSON?

e.g.: Suppose that there is a domain called "www.somedomain.com" and in this domain has an object called 'person', which countains 'name', 'age', 'heigth'. I navigate to this domain (www.somedomain.com), go to the navigator's console, type: 'person' and hit enter. After doing it, it shows me the object and its attributes.

[Example of the console thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQgc5.png)

[How the page looks like](https://jsfiddle.net/aj2ejnsc/)

What I want to do is to retrieve this object called 'person'. Something like this:

```
$domain = file_get_contents("someurl.com");
echo $domain->person;
```

Is that even possible?

@EDIT

In the end, I figured that I could simply do like this:

`echo file_get_contents("www.someurl.com");
echo "<script> document.write(person.name); </script>";`

As I'm not much familiar with PHP, I didn't knew I could "manipulate" the domain after using file_get_contents

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot parse json than definitely not with file_get_contents.

Seems like really you not completely understand - what you are doing, but still - there are some solutions.

Example - is the answer. You actualy have to "navigate" with something to your domain and evaluate javascript.

1. Something like this can be done using Selenium (https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver)
2. You can try to find some browser extension like https://github.com/scraperlab/browserext
3. You can parse javascript from web page and try to evaluate it with Google V8 Engine with something like this http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php